# Preparing LSTM Network input from multiple files

Tags: lstm, machine-learning-model, rnn, preprocessing

I would like to train LSTM Network, which should take 5 files as input and predict the 6th file. Each file contains 810000 data points (precipitation values), and each data point indices the location. So I have 810000's location's precipitation values.

Usually, LSTM network takes sequential data as input and in my case the file is generated every 5 minutes interval. Now, I have created an Array of 810000 values for each file, but I am unable to figure out how can I train the model by using these files and how can I split the train_set and test_set out of available files. Below attached sample code:

```
def model(self, folder_name):
        files = os.listdir(folder_name)
        files_list = []
        output = []

        for i in range(len(files)):
            files_list.append(files[i])
            if len(files_list) == 6:
                output.append(files_list)
                files_list = []

        if files_list:
            output.append(files_list)

        if len(output) > 0 and len(output[-1]) < 6:
            remaining = output.pop()
            last_list = output[-1] + remaining
            output[-1] = last_list

        for _filelist in output:
            X = _filelist[:5]
            y = _filelist[-1]
            train_data = np.empty((len(X), 810000))

            for i in range(len(X)):
                binary_reader = BinaryReader()
                train_data = np.array(
                    binary_reader.file_reader(f"{folder_name}\\{X[i]}")
                )
            y = np.array(binary_reader.file_reader(f"{folder_name}\\{y}")).reshape(
                (-1,)
            )
```

output:

```
[[0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 ...
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]] [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
[[0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 ...
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]] [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
[[0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 ...
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]] [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
```

In the sample folder the 20 files are available so I am giving the model the first 5 files as input.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import *
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.losses import MeanSquaredError
from keras.metrics import RootMeanSquaredError
from keras.optimizers import Adam

model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(InputLayer((5,1)))
model1.add(LSTM(64))
model1.add(Dense(8,'relu'))
model1.add(Dense(1,'linear'))

model1.summary()
```

Now I want to feed the LSTM Network with the available with the specific input shape. Can somebody help me out with this situation?